# How to detect event for underlaying layer

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a grid in which contents are added in listview.I have added another grid which is an overlay over listview. I need to scroll the items in underlying grid.

```
 <Grid>
        <ListView>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
            <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        </ListView>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="All"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Please provide an example following this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you remove the `Background="Transparent"` from the overlay `Grid` or set `IsHitTestVisible="False"`, the mouse events should reach the `ListView`. If thats not working or if the overlay grid contains more content, you may have to capture mouse events and explicitely relay them to the listview.

Comment: @grek40 I need to manipulate the overlay grid events as well as to scroll the items in listview. suggest me please

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the mouse event (or better, the `PreviewMouseWheel` event) and explicitely re-raise it for the listview:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listview1">
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
        <TextBlock Text="CONTENT"/>
    </ListView>
    <Grid Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseWheel="Grid_PreviewMouseWheel"/>
</Grid>
```

Code for forwarding the event:

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Handled)
    {
        Decorator border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listview1, 0) as Decorator;
        ScrollViewer sv = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
        var arg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta) { RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent, Source = sender };
        sv.RaiseEvent(arg);
    }
}
```

Note I just used the first way I found in order to get to the `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListView`, there may be better / more save / ... ways to do it.

Optionally, flag `e.Handled = true;` if you don't need the mouse wheel event on the overlay anymore.

Comment: Please suggest me for touch events for windows10

Comment: @shalusri sorry, I use neither windows 10 nor a touch device. But if you forward the touch events `PreviewTouchDown` `PreviewTouchUp` `PreviewTouchMove` in a simular way as I forward the `MouseWheelEvent`, it should be working. Just remember to capture the `Preview[SomeEvent]` and raise the `[SomeEvent]`.